# VSCode does not recognize unit tests? (Xunit)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I know that this has probably been asked before but I simply cannot get it to work.

My cloned repository looks like this:

```
mycompany-be
    .config
    .git
    .github
    ...
    Contracts
    Controllers
    ...
    MyCompany.csproj
    TestProject
        TestProject.csproj
        MyTest.cs
```

However, even after adding

```
  "dotnet-test-explorer.treeMode": "flat"
```

or

```
  "dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "TestProject/"
```

It wont work. However, if I go to MyTest.cs and press on "Run All Tests" (which is an option in the code) I get the following output on terminal:

**error MSB3202: The project file "c:\Users\xyz\Documents\GitHub\TestProject\TestProject.csproj" was not found.**